# Algorithm to remove childs from array

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, data-structures, tree

I have to write an `algorithm` for my project. Following is the problem

A Tree like Structure for which only one functionality is exposed i.e to `**getAllChildNodes**` which returns all the children of a particular node.
Now I am given an array of Nodes , I have to only retain the topmost parent node among them.

Example : Lets say there are 3 trees

```
Tree 1 : P1 has two children C11 & C12

Tree 2 : P2 has 1 children C21, and C21 has 2 child C22, C23

Tree 3 : P3 has 2 Children C31 and C32

Now if given an array say { C11, C21, C22 , P1, P3, C32}
 The expected result is { C21, P1 , P3 }
```

Let me know if more information is required from my side.

More info :
I have done it by first getting all the child of first element of array and then compare with rest of the elements of array ,and similarly with each element. but this has more complexity.. i.e n*n*getAllChildNodes. I am here for a better suggestion

Comment: I am trying to do it first getting all the child of first element of array and then compare with rest of the elements of array , but this has more complexity.. i.e n*n*getAllChildNodes. I am here for a better suggestion

Comment: Could you get another function say getParentNode(childNode)? If you could get it then just have parentNodes of all child node and simply remove duplicates.

Comment: No such method available

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pick ith element of array and add all its children to a hashmap(using the given function). Do this for i 1 to n(complete pass)

Loop i for 1 to n and for each iteration, check if the element is present in hashmap.

If it is present, delete it from the array,

else continue

Note the order of checking if element belong to hashmap is O(1) and also order of addition is O(1), avearage. So the algorithm is O(n*getAllChlidNodes) average

Comment: Ya you will need to do complete pass first

Comment: Yes, the order will be same, O(nk)+O(nk)=O(nk)

Comment: But I think that You have forget to consider it in your algorithm So it will not be correct, right?

Comment: But here k=n-1 so O(n(n-1))~O(n*n)

Comment: Yes but you have to use the given function anyways (you cant creat custom functions for the tree like getting parent) so you cant help that factor

Comment: You do know that creating a `getParent()` method is way more efficient than the `getChild()` method right??

Comment: Yes depending on implementation but read the question, it clearly states only one function is exposed

Comment: @Adi Sorry, but I dont have any getParent() method. And in your solution what will be the key and what will be the value of the hashmap

Comment: The algorithm does not use getParent(), key will be the 'node value/node number' and value will be 1 if present. See [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) and [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_hashmap_class.htm) for more on hashmaps

Comment: You just need [containsKey](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#containsKey(java.lang.Object)) function basically

Comment: Please leave a comment if there is some other issue. Otherwise will appreciate if you accept the answer

Comment: I only need the topmost member of the tree . How is that condition worked upon here ??

Comment: Because if it is not topmost, it will be in the hashmap and will be deleted on the second pass.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily.
first create a method `isPresent(node)` to check if the node you are entering is present in the array. Then enter each node given to find its parent.

```
if(isPresent(x->parent)) push(x->parent);
```

Continue this for the entire list.
Now `recursively` check to see if the `current list` has any `parents present`. Once you start doing you'll get it. If there are any parents just `pop()` those elements.
Hope this helps :)

Comment: The main purpose of algorithm is not using custom functions like finding parent as far as I can infer from the question. The question says only getAllChildNodes is exposed.

Answer (score 0):

If you could get a function first like getParentNode(childNode) or create map/multimap of child as key and parent as value as pre processing step then Problem would become very easy.

If you have  getParentNode(childNode) then just walk through the array and push the parents into set.

If you have map/multimap of child as key and parent as value as pre processing step then apply the algo as mentioned by [adi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17311930/algorithm-to-remove-childs-from-array/17312045#17312045)

Comment: Sorry I dont have any function to get the ParentNod